# Chrome Extension - Append Element to Another Element by Class Name

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have a JS script that appends a div element under another element on the page by class name, though it doesn't seem to be working.

```
var divthing = document.createElement("div");
divthing.setAttribute("class", "div-thing");
document.getElementsByClassName("page-element-class").appendChild(divthing);
```

I have another script that does something similar, but works. I have no idea why this script doesn't work.
Any help in figuring this out is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a [nodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), not an element. Instead use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("page-element-class")[0].appendChild(divthing);
```

Comment: This only seems to be getting appended to the first element with the class, is there any way to append it to all elements with that class?

Comment: @Starletts: You would have to loop through the nodelist. Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JX8PL/).

Comment: Thanks, does the for loop automatically stop after there are no more elements with that class?